# Clear input event - HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this piece of HTML and JavaScript

```js
function validate() {
    const tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    const input = tabs[currentTab].querySelectorAll("input[type=tel], input[type=text], input[type=time], input[type=number], input[type=email]");
    const radio = tabs[currentTab].querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
    const select = tabs[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("select");
    let valid = true;
    if (radio.length == 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input[i].value == "") {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
            if (select[i].value == "") {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else if (radio[0].name == "phnum" && radio[0].checked) {
        if (input[0].value == "" || input[1].value == "") {
            valid = false;
        }
    } else if (radio[1].name == "phnum" && radio[1].checked) {
        if (input[0].value == "" || input[1].value == "" || input[2].value == "") {
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        document.getElementById("next").className = "prevNext";
    }
}
```

```html
    <span id="radio">
     <label for="phnum1" class="radio-container">
       <input type="radio" name="phnum" id="phnum1" value="1" onchange="displayPhone(this);">1 Number
          <span class="radio"></span>
     </label>
     <label for="phnum2" class="radio-container">
       <input type="radio" name="phnum" id="phnum2" value="2" onchange="displayPhone(this);">2 Numbers
       <span class="radio"></span>
     </label>
     <label for="phnum3" class="radio-container">
       <input type="radio" name="phnum" id="phnum3" value="3" onchange="displayPhone(this);">3 Numbers
       <span class="radio"></span>
     </label>
    </span>
   </p><br>
   <p id="ph1"  class="disable">
      <label for="phone-number1">Add a Phone Number: </label><input type="tel" name="phone-number1" id="phone-number1" class="input" placeholder="Add A Phone Number" required oninput="validate();">
   </p>
   <p id="ph2" class="disable">
      <label for="phone-number2">Add a Phone Number: </label><input type="tel" name="phone-number2" id="phone-number2" class="input" placeholder="Add A Phone Number" required onchange="validate();">
  </p>
  <p id="ph3" class="disable">
      <label for="phone-number3">Add a Phone Number: </label><input type="tel" name="phone-number3" id="phone-number3" class="input" placeholder="Add A Phone Number" required onchange="validate();">
  </p>
```

that handles the input added by the user to make a button clickable if all necessary data is added. the problem is when i delete inside the input with back arrow key(the one above enter) the button remains active even if the condition for its activation no longer applies.
thank you guys for your time and help i really do appreciate it. :D

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you, you should fix the error reported in the console first. Also, just insert one code snippet and place the appropriate language code in one of the 3 boxes.

Comment: there is no error and everything with my code works fine, excepts it ignores the fact that when i clear the input the button remains functional. and i didn't understand the part about the 3 boxes i'd appreciate it if you could explain it. thanks

Comment: What's the value of `currentTab`? I don't see it declared in your snippet.

Comment: the current tab is just to go through the forms as i use a multiphase form. the currentTab just refers to the phase of the form in which there will be verification. as i said everything works fine except for the part when i empty out one of the fields, the button i want to disable remains enabled

Comment: The code you provided here in your question throws an error because there are functions that you didn't include. We need to see those functions.

Comment: it's ok scott i already found the problem and it's a stupid one, i just forgot to add an else. thanks for your time though and for the help i really do appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I see - you're setting the class name if `valid == true` via `document.getElementById("next").className = "prevNext";`.

But nowhere are you removing that class name if `valid == false`.

That's probably why you aren't seeing the button disappear when you empty out the fields (if I understand your problem correctly).

`if (!valid) { document.getElementById("next").className = ""; }` is a quick and dirty way to get what you need.

Comment: yeah i just noticed that i forgot to add the else, thanks alot man i really feel stupid for having this problem. appreciate the help